# Finding poles of a function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Is there a command to find the poles of a function $f=f(z)$?

example: let $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-1}$$ then we know that the poles are at 
$z=\pm 1$ but is there a special command in mathematica to do this?

Comment: `Solve[1/f[z] == 0, z]`?

Comment: OK I thought there was some special command like Pole[f,z] or similar. Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Or, if you want to handle things like `Tan[]`: `Reduce[1/Tan[x] == 0, x]]`. Should work nicely for rational functions, too.

Comment: @J. M. I think that is easier/smoother.

Comment: It really depends. If you're dealing with rational functions only, use `Solve[]`, as @Michael recommended. `Reduce[]` takes a bit more effort internally...

Comment: sometimes I use `Solve[Denominator[f[z]]==0,z]`, but I would say this question is good because I also expect something much easier and more automatic (in case one doesn't want to organize the expression of `f[z]`).

Comment: In 13 version of Mathematica you can just use FunctionPoles experemental function! https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/FunctionPoles.html

Answer (score 14):

There is a special function for this: it's called `TransferFunctionPoles`. For the case you asked for:

```
TransferFunctionPoles[TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(z^2 - 1)}}, z]]
```

which returns the expected answer that there are two poles at

```
{{{-1, 1}}}
```

`TransferFunctionPoles` can also handle multivariable input/output models of the kind that control engineers like to play with, including symbolic transfer functions and time-delay systems. There are a number of related commands including `TransferFunctionZeros`, `TransferFunctionModel`, `StateSpaceModel` ways of converting continuous to discrete models, and special plotting functions like `RootLocusPlot` and `NyquistPlot`.

Comment: It doesn't work with `Tan[z]`.  It complains about polynomial numerators and denominators.  Is this method restricted to rational functions?

Comment: @@Michael E2 -- Whenever you see the phrase "transfer function," it implies rational functions.

Answer (score 4):

Since V 13.0 we have `FunctionPoles`:"

From the documentation: *"FunctionPoles returns a list of pairs {pole, multiplicity}."*

```
f = 1 / (z^2 - 1);

FunctionPoles[f, z]
```

{{-1, 1}, {1, 1}}

To only get the poles:

```
{a, b} = FunctionPoles[f, z][[All, 1]]
```

{-1, 1}

```
Plot[f, {z, -10, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{a, 0}, {0, 1}], InfiniteLine[{b, 0}, {0, 1}]},
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `FunctionDomain` to find the real domain, then remove the whole line from the domain found. What is left are the poles. (this is all on the real line)

```
ClearAll[f,z]
f         = 1/(z^2-1)
domain    = FunctionDomain[f,z,Reals];
wholeLine = -Infinity < z < Infinity;

Reduce[ wholeLine && Not[domain],z,Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f         = Tan[z];
domain    = FunctionDomain[f,z,Reals];
wholeLine = -Infinity<z<Infinity;

Reduce[ wholeLine && Not[domain],z,Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works for 2D also

```
ClearAll[f,x,y]
f         = 1/x Log[y];
domain    = FunctionDomain[f,{x,y},Reals];
wholeLine = {-Infinity<x<Infinity && -Infinity<y<Infinity};

Reduce[Join[wholeLine,{Not[domain]}],{x,y},Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In 13 FunctionPoles...