# Order of a pole

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex

Is there a simple way to determine the order of the poles of a *rational* function?

I have a difficult function where I need *Mathematica* to find the poles. It would be interesting to also know what the order is. Does there exist a basic command?

Comment: Is your function a rational function?

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted exactly what your "difficult function" looks like.

Comment: Yes @JohnMcGee it is a rational function.

Comment: @J. M. I really don't think it would be illuminating if I explicitly gave you this function. Also I just wanted to know if this was possible in general.

Comment: Well, as noted, rational functions are easy. Transcendentals will require some work, since nothing's built-in.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/finding-poles-of-a-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One quick way for *rational functions* is to leverage built-in control system functions:

```
TransferFunctionPoles[TransferFunctionModel[1/(1 + s^2), s]][[1, 1]]
   {-I, I}
```

Comment: This only gives me the poles, not the order...

Comment: You can use `Tally[]` for that. ;)

Comment: Ah nice, I understand. TransferFunctionPoles will give the solution multiple times in contrast to Solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yo can go by solving the inverse of the function and then `Count` the solution.

```
f[x_] := x/(a - x)^3/(b - x);
div = x /. Solve[1/f[x] == 0, x];
poles = Union[div]
Count[div, #] & /@ poles
```

> {a,b}
>
> {3,1}

Depending on how complicated your function is, you may have to go for numerical treatment, like `NSolve` or `NRoots`.

> Tally

As Guess who it is suggests, You can use `Tally[div]` instead of `Count`.

For some reason I always forget the right command at right time :] .

Comment: Thanks! This works. As alternatives you mean Reduce?

Comment: You could, of course, use `Solve[]`/`Reduce[]` on `Denominator[f[x]]`.

Comment: @cherzieandkressy, if your function is too heavy for `Solve` then you may have to go numeric, like `NSolve` or `NRoots`.